# print php session username

Tags: php, session, tags

I am trying to get the username from the logged in user to display on a forum post.  When the user creates a topic or answers a thread, their username is automatically printed on their post.  My forum is super basic and already connects to a seperate database.

I validate my login pages with the following:

```
    <?php session_start(); 
    if(!session_is_registered(myusername)) { 
    header("location:home.php"); 

} 
?>
```

Also, I want to make sure that the username that is posted remains on their post after they have logged out, and when the post is viewed by other members.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to print the poster's name on the post, not the user that's logged in?

Comment: Well the user that is making the post is the user that is logged in.  The forum is in a members section

Comment: How are you checking that the login is valid on every page load? You should write that, which usually will end up with you filling $_SESSION with the information you need.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to receive the username, you must be storing it somehow. If you are storing it using $_SESSION['username'] = 'Username'; then getting it is an simple as using the variable $_SESSION['username'].

Answer (score 0):

which your php version? In the PHP 5.3 this function session_is_registred() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing the user name in something like $_SESSION['username'] or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use session_register() and session_is_registered() for checking session variable because it's deprecated. I suggest you do like this :

```
// save variable session
$_SESSION['username']= "your_usename";

// check variable session
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("location:home.php"); 
}
```